# Insert div within div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create and insert a div **within** an already dynamically created div:

```
var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
var inner = "stuff";
parentDiv.innerHTML = inner;
someRootDiv.appendChild(parentDiv);

var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
inner = "more stuff";
childDiv.innerHTML = inner;
parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv);
```

But the child div isn't displayed within the parent div, it's displayed below it as if it's just a following div. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/e5qTq/ — Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Huh, what do you mean by "displayed below like a following div"? You append the `childDiv` to the `parentDiv` correctly, but of course a block-element is displayed in the line below the `"stuff"` text

Comment: It is really not inside? I mean, It should be at the bottom of `parentDiv`.

Comment: I mean in the sense I want to have the child div appear nested within the parent div (so the parent acts as a container).

Comment: @Destini — It does appear nested within the parent div.

Comment: hmmm then it must be something I'm doing in the CSS which is making it appear outside (and below). Thanks.

Comment: edit: it is inside, it just looked like it wasn't, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted does put a div inside another one ([Demo of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ft8AE/)). Are you referring to the fact that they don't align side by side, [the way spans would](http://jsfiddle.net/svAWU/)?

This would be because of divs being block elements, whereas spans are inline. You could alter this by changing their display mode in CSS:

```
display: inline;
```

or simply switch to using spans.

Comment: You could add padding around childDiv, and it would be more obvious.

Comment: I think I am indeed being an idiot, the display was misleading, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
var inner = "stuff";
parentDiv.innerHTML = inner;
someRootDiv.appendChild(parentDiv);

var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
inner2 = "more stuff";
childDiv.innerHTML = inner2;
parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv);​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U2hSS/)

Comment: Spot the difference answers are generally not good answers. It looks like you are suggesting "Don't use the `inner` variable again". There is no need to use a different variable to hold the second string … and if you were to use one, it shouldn't be a global.

Answer (score -1):

Few changes required.

Try This :

```
<script>
function fun(){
var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
var inner = "stuff data";
parentDiv.innerHTML = inner;
document.getElementById("maindiv").appendChild(parentDiv);

var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
inner = "more stuff inside parent Div";
childDiv.innerHTML = stuff;
parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv);

}
</script>
```

Inside body tag :-

```
<body onload="fun()">
<div id="maindiv">

</div>
</body>
```

it works ok.Hope it will help you.